# Splitting a string into words and punctuation with java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to split a string up into words and punctuation, adding the punctuation to the list produced by the split.

For instance:
`String c = "help, me!"`

I want out the list to look like is:

`['help', ',', 'me', '!']`

So, I want the string split at whitespace with the punctuation split from the words.
Do you have ideas how to do it?

Comment: I have updated my answer and it works now with the second regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `regex` as follows:

```
String d = Str.split("\\W+");
```

Updated answer for your question:

```
String d = Str.split("\\b");
```

Comment: you are making me jealous ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki, Haha. :). Why?

Comment: the rate at which your reps is increasing :-/

Comment: I have output here ['help' 'me']

Comment: @AmitJoki, Thank you :). I will take that as a compliment.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted and voted up--Neither of the supplied examples gives the desired output on the asker's test case, it gives either ["help", "me"] or ["help", ", ", "me" "!"]--notice the extra space after the comma in the second token.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
String str = "help, me!";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ", !", true);
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());;
        }
```

Output:

```
help
,
   <- space
me
!
```

Comment: note: add any your separator in second argument of StringTokenizer's constructor if you have more